# Deploy a .rdl on ReportServices by code behind

Tags: c#, reporting-services

I'm working on a software that make some test on report before sent it to production.

Is there a method to send report on the ReportService with C# ?
And is there a method to send parameter to ReportService and catch the result (not the pdf, but the result of the operation) ?

Thanks for your attention.

EDIT : To add some information, I need the same behavior in C# as if I choose 'deploy' from Visual Studio with a TargetServerURL and TargetReportFolder.

Comment: Do You mean: deploy report so other users will see it on Report Server or You mean to tell ReportService to process .rdl only once and not deploy it on server? What exact result of operation do You expect? Report dataset result? Rendered HTML?

Comment: I have report on local computer and I need to deploy it on ReportService (RS is located on a server). Next I do to process the rdl and catch if all is ok (as missing subreport, incorrect storedprocedure or anything that crash a report).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into using the [ReportService2005.asmx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152787%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) (or appropriate version).

See the [`CreateReport`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2005.reportingservice2005.createreport.aspx) method.